# What are proper numerical methods to solve IVP at irregular singular point?

Tags: numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, singular-values

I have searched for numerical methods to solve IVP with irregular singular points but didn't find any.

What is a proper method I can use to solve such equations?

For example, we could consider the following:
$$
\begin{cases}
y''+\dfrac{y'}{x^2}+y=x^3+6x+3\\
y(0)=0, \\y'(0)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
I'm not interested in this particular problem, it's only an example.

Comment: Wait why can't you just regularise and adapt to the initial values?